# Javascript gallery works only once

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, image-gallery

I've made a simple image gallery using W3.css and javascript. Each image is a w3-card with text under it and takes one third of the screen (using w3-third). I got the javascript to zoom the image and move it the front ( so it is visible) on click and make it go back on second click. The proble is, once the image goes back, clicking it does nothing. Here is the code for the gallery.html (without the header, as it has nothing to do with gallery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Strona Główna</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-light-green.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/closeAll.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="Shortcut icon" href="../img/facin.ico" /> -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="w3-container  w3-theme-l3">
    <div class="w3-row">
            <div class="w3-container w3-third">
                <div class=" w3-container w3-card w3-sand">
                    <img
                        src="https://docs.gimp.org/en/images/filters/examples/color-taj-sample-colorize.jpg"
                        alt="img1" style="width: 100%;" onclick="onClick(this)">
                    <div class="w3-container">
                        <p>image 1</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-container w3-third w3-sand">
                <div class="w3-container w3-card">
                    <img
                        src="http://www.techalliance.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/sample-image-300X300.jpg"
                        alt="img2" style="width: 100%" onclick="onClick(this)">
                    <div class="w3-container">
                        <p>image 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-container w3-third">
                <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-sand">
                    <img
                        src="http://www.freevectors.net/files/large/FloralFrameWithSampleText.jpg"
                        alt="img3" style="width: 100%" onclick="onClick(this);">
                    <div class="w3-container">
                        <p>img3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<footer class="w3-container w3-theme w3-text-black-opacity w3-small">
    <br>
    <div align="center">Copyright&copy; killermenpl 2015. All rights
        reserved</div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-tiny">
        Uses
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/">W3.css</a>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for galeria.js

```
function onClick(element) {
//alert("onclick");
// if (element.tagName != "img") {
// alert("not an image");
// return;
// }

if (!element.dataset.zoom) {
    element.dataset.zoom = "0";
}

if (element.dataset.zoom == "0") {
    element.dataset.zoom = "1";
    element.dataset.zindex = element.style.zIndex;

    element.style.position = "relative";
    element.style.zIndex = 100;

    element.style.width = "300%";
    element.style.height = "300%";

    //alert("zoom!");
} else {
    //alert("zoom!");
    element.style.zIndex = element.dataset.zindex;

    element.dataset.zoom == "0";

    element.style.width = "100%";
    element.style.height = "100%";
}
}
```

It's probably something stupid that everyone should know about, but I'm new to javascript and kind of new to css. Also, I know the images don't align to the middle of the screen when zoomed in. I'll add it later.

Comment: where is `onClick()` assigned   to any event

Comment: I copied my index.html instead of gallery.html. My bad. Fixing it right now. There isn't much difference. Basically every <img> has `onclick="onClick(this);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line in the `else` statement :

```
element.dataset.zoom == "0";
```

to this:

```
element.dataset.zoom = "0";
```

for assignments you should use '=' instead of '=='.

And if you want images to zoom at its center origin you should use CSS3 `trasform: scale(x,y);` attribute and scale the element. for example:

```
element.style.transform = "scale(1.5,1.5)";
```

and for webkit browsers:

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1.5,1.5)";
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something trivial. I think I need to get a new keyboard, as I've noticed this one sometimess registers one click twice.